# how to create a splunk CSV file?

Tags: csv, splunk

build script to

a) check the size of all lookup files in splunk

b) if size exceeds a specific threshold download the csv file

c) delete the lookup file or recreate a dummy lookup file

Comment: Do you want to do that in a Splunk search or via the command line?  Why?  Lookup files usually are to enrich searches so emptying them out would be counter-productive.

Comment: I need to do using splunk search.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way to get the size of a lookup file in SPL.  You would have read the file using `inputlookup` and compute the size by adding up the lengths of each field, remembering to account for separators and the header.
You can test the calculated size against a defined limit, but there is no functionality for changing the behavior of a query based on the result of such a test.
This would be far easier to do in a shell script.
What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Where I can run the shellscript if the splunk is in cloud?

Comment: You can't.  Running in Splunk Cloud changes everything and would have been good to know from the beginning.
So let's start over.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

You can get this via the REST command, hitting the lookup-table-files endpoint. Check out the docs here: https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/SplunkCloud/latest/RESTREF/RESTknowledge#data.2Fprops.2Flookups

As an example, try this search:

```
| rest splunk_server=local /services/data/lookup-table-files/
| rename eai:acl.app as app 
| table app title 
| search NOT title IN (*.kmz) 
| map maxsearches=990 search="| inputlookup $title$ 
| eval size=0
| foreach * [ eval size=size+coalesce(len('<<FIELD>>'),0), app=\"$app$\", title=$title$ | fields app title size]" 
| stats sum(size) by app title
| sort - sum(size)
```

(which I found here when trying to do the same thing https://www.pixelchef.net/find-size-lookup-files-splunk-web, and which worked for me)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).